# Mouse pointer doesn't change back to default arrow and gets stuck as a resize-icon or text-edit-icon

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, mouse, bug

The mouse pointer on my MacBook Pro M1 gets stuck as a resize-icon or text-edit-icon.

**A specific example case where this happens:**
When I'm in Finder and cross over between the main window (with all my folders and files) and the sidebar on the left, the resize-icon appears on the border between the two windows. This seems like normal behavior. However, when moving on, the resize icon is still there instead of shifting back to the default pointer arrow. Even selecting a file or folder does not resolve this.

The same thing happens when I click in the search bar in finder. The text-edit-icon appears and does not change back after leaving the search bar.

Any advice on how to solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is probably a OS bug that you can't do much about. the way to go is to wait for future macos updates where apple addresses this issue and fixes this bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm using a MacBook Pro w/ M1 Pro chip. I was able to fix it by doing an NVRAM reset as described in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiMfr_8KPUk).

Comment: Answers should be more than just links, please include the relevant part directly in your post.

Comment: i'm just crediting back where i found the solution and it's stated there in that video. but here's how i did it: shut down your mac,  then turn it on and immediately press and hold the cmd+option+p+r button for at least 20 seconds or until the apple logo disappears.